# Project runs ok, but when project bin folder copied to other machine, getting FileNotFound on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-assembly

My simple .NET 6 command line project builds and runs on my dev machine.  All it does is make a connection to a SQL Server instance.

I copy the entire output folder to another machine, and at runtime there I get

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'

What could be the cause?  If it's a dependency, what dependency could it be?  If it was a dependency, wouldn't I get a different exception, not FileNotFoundException? How can I diagnose this further?

Comment: Is that file in the bin folder? Or in the GAC?

Comment: How did you add your reference to `SqlClient` in your project?

Comment: @daleK. Bin folder.  This is .Net 6 - no GAC.

Comment: @DCAggie It is a package reference from a dependent project.

Comment: Can you verify that the `SqlClient` is deployed alongside the app and that the version matches exactly what is referenced in your exception? It's possible that the DLL isn't being copied or that the version copied doesn't match the exact version either your app or it's dependency expects.

Comment: @DAggie, yes, I've confirmed that  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll is present in the application folder. It is 4.1.0.0, same as the message says ,and the public key token matches (confirmed with ILSpy).  I've confirmed that the assembly came from the correct packages folder (Lib\netcoreapp3.1, the latest available).

Comment: I've reduced my repro to simply  (basically) ```var connection = new SqlConnection(args[0]))``` .  I've confirmed that in each case the runtime is 6.0.16.   Pulling my hair out.

Comment: Did you "publish" your application, or just "build"?

Comment: I found the issue and posted an answer.  Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that (at least sometimes) it is necessary to also copy the "runtimes" subfolders of the output folder.  Microsoft.Data.Sql.Client has a platform-specific runtime dependency on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll.  In my case, I needed the one for platform win-x64. THe build process populates the "runtimes" subfolder of the output folder with a copy of this dll for each supported platform.

Sometimes you can get away with not copying the runtimes subfolder, if none of your packages have platform-specific dependencies.